# Ошибка object is not iterable (Django)

Tags: python, django, обработка-ошибок

Всем привет, столкнулся с ошибкой "object is not iterable" и не пойму как её решить:

есть фрагмент кода **views.py**

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.POST['clientSearch']
        result = News.objects.get(pk=q)
        context={'result': result}
    except News.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("News does not exist")
    return render(request,'news/search.html', context)
```

при выполнении запроса происходит ошибка и debugger ссылается на мой template, на 1-ую строчку:

```
{% for result in result %}
    {{ result.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Самое интересное, что с `result = News.objects.filter(pk=q)` - всё работает.
В ходе гуглёжа я понял, что между `News.objects.filter(pk=q)` и `News.objects.get(pk=q)` есть разница, но не пойму какая.
Буду очень признателен, если скажите, что за разница между ними и как завести код с `News.objects.get(pk=q)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пишете запрос к базе через `SomeModel.objects.filter()`  - создается объект типа `queryset` со списком объектов, которые можно обходить в цикле `{% for %}`.
Если `queryset` вернет список из одного объекта, это все равно будет `queryset`, поэтому цикл у вас работал.
Когда вы пишете `SomeModel.objects.get()`, вы обращаетесь непосредственно к объекту, соответственно по нему нельзя пройтись в цикле, так же если объекта не будет в базе то Django вернет исключение, c `filter()` исключения не будет.
Почитайте в [документации Django](http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/db/queries.html) о запросах к базе, чтобы лучше понять тонкости работы ORM.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.